# Trying to add a list to the the hashmap

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, hashmap

This code should add a String array list to the maps but was unable to do it.
Using Firebase Database .

```
for (DataSnapshot posSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    keyVar =posSnapshot.getKey();
    list.add(keyVar);
    cRef= dRef.child(keyVar);
    cRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot poSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                childVar = poSnapshot.getKey();
                tempList.add(childVar);
                Log.d("Key",tempList.size()+" : " +tempList.get(i));
            }
            list2.put(list.get(i),tempList);
            tempList.clear();
            i++ ;
            Log.d("hash Map",list2.entrySet()+"");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So what *does* happen? "but was unable to do it" doesn't tell us what the result was. (A compile-time error? An execution-time error? The wrong data saved? No data saved?) How far have you got debugging it? Is your event listener called?

Comment: expected output [Male=[Pants, Shirt], Female=[Frocks, Skirt]] actual output [Male=[Pants, Shirt], Female=[Pants, Shirt]] I dont know why it also overwrites the female list as well

Comment: Well are you using the same templist the whole time? Why aren't you creating a new list in onDataChange? I suspect your map values are all jjst references to the same list object...

Comment: but after adding it to the hashmap i cleared so doesnt that changes it ?

Comment: No, that's just clearing the existing list... it's not creating a *new* list. So you end up with a map with where every value is a reference to the same empty list. (With the code that you've given, I doubt that your `hash Map` log line is actually showing any values at all. But then, we can't see half the code that's involved here...)

Comment: Hardly a day passes without this question being asked in one form or another. Is there a good duplicate somewhere?

Comment: Thank You for your help Jon Skeet was able to resolve the issue